# Django model error- "TypeError: 'xxx' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, django, django-models

I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'person' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

My model is:

```
class Investment(models.Model):
company = models.ManyToManyField("Company", related_name ="Investments_company")
financial_org = models.ManyToManyField("Financial_org", related_name ="Investments_financial_org")
person = models.ManyToManyField("Person", related_name ="Investments_person")
```

My test (that gives the error):

```
investment1 = Investment(company = [], financial_org = financial1, person = [])
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. **Instanciate your model without many to many**, `investment1 = Investment()`
2. **Save your model**, `investment1.save()`
3. **Add many to many**, there are [several ways to do it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/relations/) like `investment1.person.add(person_model)` or `investment1.person.create(name='foo')`

**You may not use a ManyToMany relation until a model is saved**, this is because a row in a ManyToMany relation table needs the pk of the models at the two sides of the relations.

Comment: How can this save a life ? thanks for the kind words though xD

Comment: Friend, Thank you for this solution, served me a lot.